# Weekly Writer's Chat: New Session?

Tags: discussion

The Tuesday afternoon chats have quite a few attendees.  We meet in [The Overlook Hotel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel) starting at 1pm Eastern time (1800 UTC) and chat for an hour or three.

The current schedule is posted [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/168/the-overlook-hotel?tab=schedule).  It seems to cover some of our Atlantic folks plus Europe.

**We'd like to find at least one more chat time that would cover people on the Pacific coast, and anyone on the Eastern seaboard who doesn't have lunchtime free.**

Rather than trying to figure it out in advance, I'd like to invite people who are interested in the weekly chats to **come to The Overlook whenever you think you would like to meet**.  If no one else is there, leave a message.  This will help us gauge who is available when and it will make it easier to determine when the best new time should be.